# jquery any of many drop downs required

Tags: jquery, select

Long time learner, first time asker...

Scenario:
I have a form which displays a table of date with Dates on column 1 and a drop down of reasons in column 2. The form can only be submitted if a reason in column 2 is selected. However, not all rows require a reason. That is, you can submit a form with three dates if only the third date lists a reason. The empty menu items are processed appropriately on the POST.

The submit button is switching states based on two verification check marks (We pass the phone # and email as values and the user selects a method to confirm). I have the select.val added which works as intended, but only on the first select. If I choose only the second select, the button remains disabled.

```
$('#phone, #email').click(function(){

        if($('#phone, #email').is(':checked') && $('select').val() != "")
        {
            enableSubmit();
        } else {
            disableSubmit();
        }

        $(this).next('#phone, #email');

    });
```

Example markup:

```
<select id="reason1">
    <option value=""></option> <!--This defaults the field to an empty label-->
    <option value="reason_a">Reason A</option>
    <option value="reason_b">Reason B</option>
    <option value="reason_c">Reason C</option>
</select>

<select id="reason2">
    <option value=""></option> <!--This defaults the field to an empty label-->
    <option value="reason_a">Reason A</option>
    <option value="reason_b">Reason B</option>
    <option value="reason_c">Reason C</option>
</select>

<select id="reason3">
    <option value=""></option> <!--This defaults the field to an empty label-->
    <option value="reason_a">Reason A</option>
    <option value="reason_b">Reason B</option>
    <option value="reason_c">Reason C</option>
</select>
```

### EDIT

As per request: http://jsfiddle.net/paladyn84/6dXmD/4/

Comment: have you tried `.each()` instead?

Comment: I don't see checkboxes named phone or email--perhaps you could make a jsFiddle to help us see what exactly you're doing?

Comment: @JFK: Yes, I've tried .each(). Perhaps it was my implementation, but the .each() caused ALL selects to require a value. I also tried a selector (such as ... $('select[value=""]')....) with similar results.

Comment: @Paul Oliver: I did not think it was necessary to include the input checkboxes and the submit button, nor the exact table, nor the rest of the form. I'll diddle a fiddle tonight since I cannot give Karl-André Gagnon's answer a try until tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `if`:

```
if($('#phone, #email').is(':checked') && $('select').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find(':selected').val()
}).length)
```

That will check if any dropdown has a value.

Here a little fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/e7wSK/1

By the way, instead of this :

```
 $('#phone, #email').click(function(){})
```

You should use change:

```
 $('#phone, #email, select').change(function(){
```

Comment: The fiddle looks promising; I'll give it a go tomorrow first thing. If I understand the code correctly, this will search (filter) the select tag, returning the value of any selected item which is required to have some length (which empty value has none)?

Comment: Not exactly. This code will select all there `select` and then what happen in the filter function is that it check in every select the value of the selected `option` and when it is empty, it remove the select itself from the `$('select')` object. Then if the object is empty (`length == 0`), it mean that no input is valid. if 2 select are not empty, length would be =2 but it doesnt matter if your code what's the length.

Comment: Benefit or value to using change over click? And also, could I include the select ('#phone, #email, select') as your example demonstrates and the reason for doing so?

Comment: Change will always be better because you can use keyboard to check/uncheck a radio/checkbox or click on its label. You can navigate through a form with tab and change select box with arrow keys. Those methods will not activate the `.click()` event. I included `select` in the selector because you can change `#phone` and `#email` the change the select box. The condition would be valid, but since you changed the select box last, it will never run the code.

Comment: Gave the code a shot and everything is working beautifully. Thank you very much!